# How to pass any URL to an APIFY task?

Tags: web-scraping, zapier, apify

There is a box to configure the "Start URL" in APIFY, but what happens if i don't know the start URL and it depends of my user input? I would like to be able to pass a variable URL to "Start URL"

Configuration of Start URL in APIFY:

[image]

I want to pass any URL automatically through an APIFY task and then scrap it.

I tried to make it automatically through Zapier, in the configuration is possible to select the URL input and pass it to APIFY, but finally it stops the task because is not able to read the format passed. Data out log from Zapier:

[image]

I think that APIFY probably lets configure dynamic input URL's but by my beginner level, probably there is something that scapes from my knowledge.

I want to be able to pass variable URL's to be scraped by APIFY.

Comment: “Scrap it” - do you mean scrape it (as in extract data from it) or “scrap” it as in throw i away like rubbish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check how input looks like in JSON format using Editor/JSON switcher on the top of input configuration.
[image]

After you switch to JSON you can easily check the structure of startUrls.
If you want to override startUrls for example in Zapier integration you can do it using Input JSON overrides field in Run Task Apify<>Zapier action.
[image]
You can override input same way using [API to run the task](https://docs.apify.com/api/v2#/reference/actor-tasks/run-collection/run-task), where you need to pass JSON as POST payload of the API request.

If you want to read more about Apify<>Zapier integration you can check article [Scrape single URL using Zapier](https://help.apify.com/en/articles/3034226-scrape-single-url-using-zapier).

Comment: The link to "Scrape single URL using Zapier" was a key for me to solve this issue, thanks you very much!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!